# node.js express-validator ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just try to write a simple node.js application, but if I use the express-validator the site is just loading and do nothing :(

"waiting on localhost", after some time an "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" error appears.

If i delete the app.use(expressValidator) the application works again.

```
var express = require('express'),
expressValidator = require("express-validator");

var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(expressValidator);
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log('get something get');
    res.render('app.jade');
});

app.post('/', function(req, res){
    console.log('get something post');
    res.render('app.jade');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the `expressValidator` function to get it to return a middleware handler:

```
app.use(expressValidator());
                        ^^ important!
```